# RTF rewriting <iframe> tags to be self closing

Tags: 2013, content-delivery, experience-manager

This may be vague, but I am searching around to find out if there are any known discrepancies using **Experience Manager** with SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 and `<iframe>` within the tags (or fields as they would traditionally be set up ootb). 
`<!-- Start Component Field: {"XPath":"tcm:Content/custom:Schema/custom:Description[1]"} -->`

I have a unique scenario where the XPM tags are placed in a downstream web app outside of the TCM. When I add a `<iframe>` to an `RTF` field, it conflicts with some other scripts on the downstream web app. So before diagnosing the web app and removing the tags - *I do not have direct control over the web app*; I just wanted to see if/what markup is friendly specifically related to XPM tags or anything within the TCM or configuration settings.

I have used iframes with RTF in the past, never had issues, just not inside the context of XPM.

I have also taken note of this post which may be a sufficient solution, but wanted to identify all scenarios from anyone's perspective rather than solving as they occur.

[Dynamic content changes when you switch between Design and Source in a rich text field](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1444/dynamic-content-changes-when-you-switch-between-design-and-source-in-a-rich-text)

Comment: I'm still not seeing exactly what the issue is, you mention "it conflicts with some other scripts on the page", but what conflicts then and are we talking third party scripts or XPM scripts that are in conflict and with what?

Comment: sorry for any confusion Bart - I have edited and adjusted the question so it isnt as specific per my implementation. But I was in fact, referring to XPM tags and either 3rd party scripts etc. or basically any `.js` that would interfere with these tags or an `<iframe>` tag within an rtf and how the field is rendered and consumed within the web app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A colleague of mine actually found this solution - RTF was rewriting the `<iframe>` tags to be self closing, which isn’t valid HTML5. I added a comment tag `<!—RTF Fix—>` inside of the iframe start and end tags, which stopped the end tag removal in this case.

Based on the Tidy settings docs (http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html#hide-endtags) We can disable this end tag removal “feature” but it gets overwritten if the setting for `output-xml` is true, which it is. We can change the output to html or xhtml in the Tidy settings *but I don’t know what the consequences of that might be..*

Does anyone know if/any direct effects of this and could share with me?

Comment: You can simply always make it `<iframe>Your browser does not support iframes</iframe>` which is valid HTML and solves the problem

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest using the user tag approach described in the post you've referenced. My experience concurs with the comment from John *'99% of the time they end up removing, copying or breaking inserted functionality'* and I prefer to abstract this kind of functionality out and if possible [remove the source tab](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/11753/disabling-the-source-tab-in-a-component) altogether.

The Editor certainly doesn't need to see the Twitter output in the RTF.

Possibly they don't need to 'see' (or be distracted with) the end output *from Twitter* in XPM so you could use the TBB to render it out as you prefer (twitter placeholder img/text etc.) [in the XPM context](http://albertromkes.com/2013/11/22/how-to-detect-if-you-are-in-the-editor-view-in-xpm-serverside/)).

Answer (score 5):

We had the same issue when integrating Google Drive content in a page with New UI in Tridion 2011 SP1. To bypass this issue, we used the following pattern instead of an iframe :

```
<object data="your_url"><param/></object>
```

Important note: the `</param>` must be specified